# Swapping strings in a string array

Tags: c++

Not sure if I'm doing it right or not. But I'm trying to display the output `cat the sideways ran` instead of `the cat ran sideways`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void doSwap(string string1, string string2);

int main() {
    string theArray[5] = {"the", "cat", "ran", "sideways"};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        doSwap(theArray[i], theArray[i+1]);
        cout << theArray[i] << " ";
    }
}

void doSwap (string string1, string string2) {
    string temp;
    temp = string1;
    string1 = string2;
    string2 = temp;
}
```

Not sure if I'm doing it correctly or not.

Comment: Pass the arguments to the function by reference, instead of by value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the strings by reference because you are mutating them. The way your code is written, you're sending temporary copies of the strings you want to swap, in effect, swapping the copies, but not swapping them in the array. Updated code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void doSwap(string string1, string string2);

int main() {
    string theArray[] = {"the", "cat", "ran", "sideways"};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof theArray)/sizeof(string); i++) {
        doSwap(theArray[i], theArray[i+1]);
        cout << theArray[i] << " ";
    }
}

void doSwap (string &string1, string &string2) {
    string temp;
    temp = string1;
    string1 = string2;
    string2 = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish your task quite easily using the `<algorithm>` library:

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> vec { "the", "cat", "ran", "sideways" };
    swap_ranges(begin(vec), begin(vec)+1, begin(vec)+1);
    swap_ranges(begin(vec)+2, begin(vec)+3, begin(vec)+3);
}
```

You don't need to make it difficult for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, this will be simple:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void doSwap (int first, int last);
string theArray[5] = {"the", "cat", "ran", "sideways"};
int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i <=4; i += 2) {
        doSwap((i-2),(i-1));
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        cout << theArray[i] << " ";
}

void doSwap (int first, int last){
    string tmp;
    tmp = theArray[first];
    theArray[first] = theArray[last];
    theArray[last] = tmp;
}
```